# Trigger fancybox with hover instead of click?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to get fancybox to trigger when the mouse is hovered over a link.

Have had no luck though... any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
/* This is basic - uses default settings */     
    $("a.inline").fancybox({ 'hideOnContentClick': false });    
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One way would be to fire the click when the hover event is triggered.

```
$("a.inline").fancybox().hover(function() {
    $(this).click();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("#div a").fancybox(
            {
                'width': '75%',
                'height': '50%',
                'autoScale': false,
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                'type': 'iframe'
            }).hover(function () {
                $(this).click();
            });
```