# Replace click event to open magnific popup with hover

Tags: javascript, wordpress, magnific-popup

My images already have a click event that opens the magnific popup lightbox, but I need to remove that and replace with a hover that opens the lightbox instead.

Tried this but no dice:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).mouseover(function(){
        jQuery('a.et_pb_lightbox_image').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
           });
</script>
```

This is my html:

```
<a href="https://blackdot.strutcreativestudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Deep-Bevel.jpg" class="et_pb_lightbox_image">
  <span class="et_pb_image_wrap">
    <img src="https://blackdot.strutcreativestudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Deep-Bevel.jpg" alt="">
  </span>
</a>
```

And this is the html when the image is clicked and the lightbox is open:

```
<div class="mfp-bg mfp-ready"></div>
<div class="mfp-wrap mfp-close-btn-in mfp-auto-cursor mfp-ready" tabindex="-1" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;">
    <div class="mfp-container mfp-s-ready mfp-image-holder">
        <div class="mfp-content">
            <div class="mfp-figure">
                <button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close">×</button>
                <figure>
                    <img class="mfp-img" alt="" src="https://blackdot.strutcreativestudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Deep-Bevel.jpg" style="max-height: 318px;">
                    <figcaption>
                        <div class="mfp-bottom-bar">
                            <div class="mfp-title"></div>
                                <div class="mfp-counter"></div>
                            </div>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mfp-preloader">Loading...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update: I'm a little closer... tried this out but no dice:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('a.et_pb_lightbox_image').bind('mouseover', function(event){
  .magnificPopup();
  });
});
</script>
```

Then I tried this out to test just the binding component, and it worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  ('a.et_pb_lightbox_image').bind('mouseover', function(event){
  alert('Hi there!');
  });
});
</script>
```

Which means its something in that `.magnificPopup();` section that is incorrect. Looked at documentation but it appears that this is correct? Can anyone tell what it is I'm missing?

Solved:

Thanks @Janis and the solution here - [Trigger fancybox with hover instead of click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725898/trigger-fancybox-with-hover-instead-of-click). Here's how I got it to finally work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('a.et_pb_lightbox_image').magnificPopup().hover(function() {
   jQuery(this).click();
  });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to trigger `click` event within your `hover` event.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, Janis! I'm a little closer, question edited to show next steps taken.

Comment: Try to understand your own code. When you execute `.magnificPopup()`, you are creating click event. Obviously, you have to that first and then within hover event you can `.trigger('click')`

Comment: Totally got me searching with the correct terminology, thanks!